# How do I paper-doll my moveclip in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm new to flash and so far it's been going good until now.

I'm having a hard time solving this problem:
I'm making a game using flash CS4 and AS3.  I want to be able to draw my "Hero" (movie clip) and then once my hero picks up a clothing piece in the game I want to be able to paper-doll (put on) that clothing (graphic).  So what I would like to do is have it so that my hero is rigged some how in the movieclip that I'm able to dynamically change that graphic on my hero.  I want it rigged so that I wont have to re-draw it for every animation.

I hope you guys understand what I'm asking.  To try to be blunt... I'm making an RPG and I'm not sure how to place armor graphics over my main character graphic dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're primarily refering to the kind of paperdoll thing you have in say Diablo 2, where you can choose what equipment your character is wearing, then the simplest way to achieve that is probably to simply have your clothing/armor as MC's and just position them on top of your character MC.

Similarily, if the armor/etc. need to show up on the character in-game, you could add the armor MC as a child of the character MC so it should stay with it without having to manually move it when the character MC moves.